# How do you prevent React Native from re-rendering all pages of rows in a ListView when DataSource is updated?

Tags: listview, react-native

My app has a ListView of about 80 rows, however, only 10 are initially rendered until the user scrolls down:

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
   renderSectionHeader={this.renderHeader}
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   removeClippedSubviews={true}
   initialListSize={10}
   scrollRenderAheadDistance={100}
   pageSize={10}
   style={{flex:1}}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}/>
```

If a user loads all 80 rows, then performs an action that changes the Data Source, it will replace all 80 rows at once, rather than just starting with the initial 10. This causes a really long lag because the rows take some time to process and render.

Is this intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

I've managed to fix it by only adding 10 rows to the datasource, and then immediately after adding the remaining 70 rows, but this feels very much like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple,

1. Clone your current data
2. Append your new data at the end
3. Use your new data in your component

Or, in code

```
...
// your list view
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
   renderSectionHeader={this.renderHeader}
   automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
   removeClippedSubviews={true}
   initialListSize={10}
   scrollRenderAheadDistance={100}
   pageSize={10}
   style={{flex:1}}
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
   onEndReached={() => {
    this._updateDataSet();
  }}/>
...
_updateDataSet() {
    var incomingData = ...; // replace with your data source
    var allData = this.state.dataSource;
    var newData = allData.push(...incomingData);
    this.setState({
      dataSource: newData
    });
}
```

This is just an example, you might need to tweak your `_updateDataSet()` or move it to `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: Thanks! Is the best practice to add rows sequentially like this rather than putting them in the DataSource all in at once? Or does it depend on the complexity of the rows/data? I just assumed that since there's initialListSize/pageSize props, adding it through an onEndReached function would be unnecessary.